# Python os.system or subprocess calls for command line automation

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I would like to be able to call some executables that take in parameters and then dump the output to a file.   I've attempted to use both os.system and subprocess calls to no avail.  Here is a sample of what I'd like python to execute for me...

```
c:\directory\executable_program.exe -f w:\directory\input_file.txt > Z\directory\output_file.txt
```

Notice the absolute paths as I will be traversing hundreds of various directories to act on files etc..

Many thanks ahead of time!

Some examples that I've tried:

```
subprocess.run(['c:\directory\executable_program.exe -f w:\directory\input_file.txt > Z\directory\output_file.txt']

subprocess.call(r'"c:\directory\executable_program.exe -f w:\directory\input_file.txt > Z\directory\output_file.txt"']

subprocess.call(r'"c:\directory\executable_program.exe" -f "w:\directory\input_file.txt > Z\directory\output_file.txt"']
```

Comment: Please post your own attempts with their errors / failures. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Run your command with`subprocess`, handle output redirection in Python instead of shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempts contain various amounts of quoting errors.

```
subprocess.run(r'c:\directory\executable_program.exe -f w:\directory\input_file.txt > Z\directory\output_file.txt', shell=True)
```

should work, where the `r` prefix protects the backslashes from being interpreted and removed by Python before the subprocess runs, and the absence of `[...]` around the value passes it verbatim to the shell (hence, `shell=True`).

On Windows you could get away with putting the command in square brackets even though it's not a list, and omitting `shell=True` in some circumstances.

If you wanted to avoid the shell, try

```
with open(r'Z\directory\output_file.txt', 'wb') as dest:
    subprocess.run(
        [r'c:\directory\executable_program.exe', '-f', r'w:\directory\input_file.txt'],
        stdout=dest)
```

which also illustrates how to properly pass a list of strings in square brackets as the first argument to `subprocess.run`.